# Working with dates in MySQL and PHP, selects incorrect date

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables:

table name: Profiles

```
ID | profile_id | dob
 1 |    59402   | 1995-02-27
 2 |    59403   | 1996-04-12
```

table name: LifeEvents

```
ID | event_date | event
 1 | 1993-01-13 | Event 1
 2 | 1995-07-19 | Event 2
 3 | 1997-04-02 | Event 3
```

`event_date` and `dob` data types are set to DATE

What I am trying to achieve is to first get the `dob` based on `profile_id` and after than to echo all `event` that happened after `dob`

The second part works great when using DOB set in PHP code like this:

```
  $date = '1995-02-27';
  $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

  $sql = "SELECT event FROM LifeEvents WHERE event_date > '$dt'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo $row["event"] . "<br>";
      }
  } else {
      echo "0 results";
  }
```

But when I replace the `$date` with select from the first table like this:

```
$date = "SELECT dob FROM Profiles WHERE profile_id = $profileID";
```

it no longer works and testing it with:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

returns something like `1970-01-01`

Any ideas what could be the problem, please?

Comment: var_dump `$date`

Comment: did you try this? $date = "SELECT DATE(dob) FROM Profiles WHERE profile_id = $profileID"; Of course you have to query this before doing anything else with it

Comment: `$date = '1995-02-27';
$dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));`
But why?

Comment: Your inital test converts an String into date object in order to place it into your statement, in your second approach there is no need to convert the date as its already in the required type for an assigment. Short, you convert not an string but an date object .. so this will fail. In order to work is you may, if it is required convert your date into string via mysql method : for example DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y- %m- %d')...

Comment: @DieterKräutl using DATE(dob) doesn't work, it returns empty value

Comment: $date is a query. Perhaps you want the result of $date

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your code correctly you are using `strtotime()` on the string:

`"SELECT dob FROM Profiles WHERE profile_id = $profileID"`

Not on an actual date.

Comment: How would you convert it into a date? Using SELECT DATE(dob) didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You only need one query:

```
SELECT e.* 
  FROM lifeevents e
  JOIN profiles p
    ON p.event_date > e.dob
 WHERE p.profile_id = :profile_id;
```

Now see about preparing and binding queries in PHP.